# Where do I put my web service?

Tags: android

I've made a little webservice for my Android App that generates a JSON Object that is parsed within the App.

I was wondering: is there a free web service that can allow me to run my application and so I can test it?

Comment: This web service is ad-free http://www.hostinger.de/

Comment: you can find many free php hosting site just google it.Also,for android apps you may want to try https://firebase.google.com/ (by Google)

Comment: try https://www.heroku.com/, you can host your webservice on their free-tier

Comment: thank you @farhan patel, this worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Some Free php hosting

- http://hostinger.co.uk
- https://www.000webhost.com/
- http://host-ed.net/

(You can find more just google it)

Some Free Cloud:

- https://www.openshift.com/ (OpenShift: PaaS by Red Hat)
- https://appengine.google.com

For android App also try Firebase https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: OK thank you; anyway maybe I've explained bad my problem: I have a java project made in Eclipse that I run via command line compiling it with maven; it then creates my webservice via Spring that answers with a JSON when a specific URL is called. You are telling me that if I upload my files in one of these services it will start to do the job I need?

Comment: php hosting can not host Spring (i.e java) so try https://www.openshift.com/.I have use hostinger.com.uk for my php site and openshift for other.See https://blog.openshift.com/spring-mvc-3-on-jboss/.Also you may search other fre  java hosting but openshift is best for me.